# Combining a variable with a number

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a inventory using an array in a game I'm making.

What I need is a way to combine a number with a variable, something like this:

```
itemBoxNumber = "itemBox" + currentItemBox;
//In this case itemBoxNumber would say itemBox1
```

that I could use to replace the itemBox1.

```
 function itemsMenuUpdate():void
    {
    for (var a:int = 0; a<maxInventory; a++){
                var currentItemBox:Number = 1;
                if(~inventory.indexOf("Potion")){
                mainMenu.itemBox1.gotoAndStop("Potion");
            }
            if(~inventory.indexOf("Hi-Potion")){
                mainMenu.itemBox1.gotoAndStop("Hi-Potion");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can only find working methods for AS2. Any help is appreciated with this.

Comment: You can use a Vector (or Array) to store all the objects you need to access, and then use currentItemBox as an index to access particular object in the Vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right, you can call a method from a `String` in AS3.

For example, if you want to call the method `itemBox1` on `mainMenu` you can do:

```
mainMenu["itemBox1"]
```

Which is the same as:

```
mainMenu.itemBox1
```

So in your example you could do this:

```
mainMenu[itemBoxNumber].gotoAndStop("Potion");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the child display object via a name (which you need to set prior). So:

```
var itemBoxNumber = "itemBox" + currentItemBox;
mainMenu.getChildByName(itemBoxNumber).gotoAndStop("Potion"); //TODO ensure the child was given such a name
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a LabelNumber Class, which has both a String label and a Number. You can then add a method that returns a String of the label and the number combined, while keeping the values independent of one another.